# Retrieve and order data from two columns

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting to get confused. I have an `user` model and an `event` models. A user can create an event, he is the owner. But he can also get invited to an event, he is a guest. The first relation is a OneToMany relation and the other one is a ManyToMany relation.

Now, I would like to retrive all the events of an user, owned or guest. Every events and order them by the field `date`.

This my user model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Get the events of the user.
     */
    public function owned_events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event', 'owner_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the events list.
     */
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')
                    ->using('App\Invitation')
                    ->withPivot('status')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is the event model :

```
class Event extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the owner of the event.
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guests list.
     */
    public function guests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                    ->using('App\Invitation')
                    ->withPivot('status')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

This is what I tried (inside an EventRepository)

```
/**
 * Return all the events (owner and guest) of a user ($id).
 */
public function all($id)
{
    $guested = $this->event->guests()->where('user_id', $id)->get()->load('owner', 'guests');
    $own = $this->event->where('owner_id', $id)->get()->load('owner', 'guests');

    return $guested->merge($own)->sortBy('date');
}
```

It works... but it gives me only the owned events, not where my user is the guest... I think that there is a much better way to do it. Two calls for one request is pretty bad and two loads is even worse no?

Comment: A event can have many guest, so I guess One to many relationship will be there  (On guest function hasMany relation ).

Comment: An user can be guest of many events, so it's a ManyToMany relation no?

Comment: did you try uisng `wherePivot`? `$this->event->guests()->wherePivot('user_id', $id)->get()`

Comment: Still doesn't work, I should have 7 events and I have only 5, the 5 created by my user..

Comment: And when I dd($guested), it's empty...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution :

```
$user = Auth::user()->load('owned_events', 'events'));
$events = $user->events->merge($user->owned_events)->sortBy('date');

return view('events.index', compact('events'));
```

Go throught the event model was way too hard while go throught the user model is much easier :)